# Calling C# DLL method from python via wine

Tags: c#, python, ctypes, wine

I have a DLL with a single method, written in C# as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

public class calculate
{
    [DllExport("fillArray", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static double[,] fillArray(double a, double b)
    {
        double[,] tmp = new double[Convert.ToInt32(a), Convert.ToInt32(b)];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(a); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Convert.ToInt32(b); j++)
            {
                double u1 = 1.0 - rand.NextDouble(); //uniform(0,1] random doubles
                double u2 = 1.0 - rand.NextDouble();
                double randStdNormal = Math.Sqrt(-2.0 * Math.Log(u1)) *
                Math.Sin(2.0 * Math.PI * u2); //random normal(0,1)
                tmp[i, j] = randStdNormal;
            }
        }
        return tmp;
    }
}
```

I am on OSX Mojave 10.14.6. I am using `wine` and `zugbruecke` built on top of `ctypes` to access  the method from python. Code follows.

```
import os, sys

if any([sys.platform.startswith(os_name) for os_name in ['linux', 'darwin', 'freebsd']]):
    import zugbruecke as ctypes
    dlltype="x86"
elif sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    import ctypes
    dlltype="x64"

# don't forget to set dllpath to wherever your dll is

cfunc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(dllpath).fillArray
cfunc.argtypes = (ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double)
cfunc.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double)
result = cfunc(n, m)
rarray = [result[i] for i in xrange(n * m * ctypes.sizeof(ctypes.c_double))]
```

Code breaks with an `EOFError` exception.

All assistance in identifying the problem with the python code or otherwise is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure `zugbruecke` allows to call into C# binaries? From what I understand it allows to call Windows DLLs from Unices, but this seems to imply that the Windows DLL is a **C** DLL.

Comment: I am not sure. I'd really appreciate ideas on alternate possible paths if not though.

Comment: If your function is exposed through the `cdecl` calling convention as "CallingConvention.Cdecl" suggests, it should be possible to call it through `ctypes`, i.e. it should also be possible to call it through `zugbruecke`. I am the developer of `zugbruecke` ;) I have not yet tested calling into C# DLLs, but I'd be very interested to test it (and add another relevant test case to the library) if you could provide me with a compiled DLL and its source. Besides, your code is allocating memory and returning a pointer to it. `zugbruecke` requires `memsync` directives for a case like that.